# Is this a good way to make my function, which previously expected lists, to work with all iterables?

Tags: python, list, functional-programming, iterable

I have written the following function for doing linear regression with 2 parameters(the actual math behind it is not that relevant to this question). It takes two functions, `f1`, `f2`, and two lists `xs`, `ys`:

```
def lr2par(f1, f2, xs, ys):
    c11 = sum(map(lambda x: (f1(x))**2, xs))
    c12 = sum(map(lambda x: f1(x) * f2(x), xs))
    c22 = sum(map(lambda x: (f2(x))**2, xs))
    d1 = sum(map(lambda x, y: y*f1(x), xs,ys))
    d2 = sum(map(lambda x, y: y*f2(x), xs,ys))

    a1 = -(c22*d1 - c12*d2)/(c12*c12 - c11*c22)
    a2 = (c12*d1 - c11*d2)/(c12*c12 - c11*c22)

    return (c11, c12, c22, d1, d2, a1, a2)
```

It works as expected as long `xs` and `ys` are lists. However, as you can see it is written in a quite functional style, so of course I would like to be able to use this function elegantly in functional code. That includes calling a function like `map` on a list before i input it to the function, like the `ys` argument in this example:

```
lr2par(lambda x: x, lambda x: 1, [1, 3, 5, 7], map(math.log, [130, 150, 175, 210]))
```

This looks very natural to me, and I would expect it to work(I am a python noob though). Turns out it does not. I am quite sure the problem is that the `ys` argument is now no longer a list, but an iterator(which seems to be the main type when working with the functional tools in python) that can only be iterated over once, so when it comes to the line

```
d2 = sum(map(lambda x, y: y*f2(x), xs,ys))
```

`ys` is just empty. I want to solve this problem in an idiomatic functional pythonic way. My current solution is to add the lines

```
xs = list(xs)
ys = list(ys)
```

to the start of the function body. This works, but is this a good way to solve the problem? Will I have to add these lines to almost all functions that uses collections of objects and are expected to work nice with functions like `map`, `filter` and `zip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can't iterate over an iterable twice. If you need to, you must convert it to a sequence first, as you did with `list` -- that is actually a pretty standard solution.

The main problem with that is that it's potentially inefficient, because it copies any lists or tuples coming in, so you might want to check for those and replace `list` with this helper function:

```
from collections import Sequence  # ABC for lists and tuples

def tosequence(it):
    """Convert iterable to sequence, avoiding unnecessary copies."""
    return it if isinstance(it, Sequence) else list(it)
```

(And as a site note, your code gets much more readable if you replace `map` and `lambda` with generator comprehensions; it may also become a lot *faster* if you rewrite it to use NumPy, which I'd recommend for any number crunching in Python.)